# How I filter noisy data on column in apache spark maven project?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I m working on Apache Spark on java maven project.I have a subreddit comments like that in the this figure;

```
     +--------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+------------+-----+------------+----------+------------+---+
|archived|        author|author_flair_css_class|author_flair_text|                body|controversiality|created_utc|distinguished|downs|edited|gilded|     id| link_id|      name| parent_id|retrieved_on|score|score_hidden| subreddit|subreddit_id|ups|
+--------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+------------+-----+------------+----------+------------+---+
|    true|       bostich|                  null|             null|                test|               0| 1192450635|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299an|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299an|  t3_5yba3|  1427426409|    1|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  1|
|    true|igiveyoumylife|                  null|             null|much smoother.

...|               0| 1192450639|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299ao|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299ao|  t3_5yba3|  1427426409|    2|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  2|
|    true|          Arve|                  null|             null|Can we please dep...|               0| 1192450643|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299ap|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299ap|t1_c02999p|  1427426409|    0|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  0|
|    true|     [deleted]|                  null|             null|           [deleted]|               0| 1192450646|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299aq|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299aq|  t3_5yba3|  1427426409|    1|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  1|
|    true|     gigaquack|                  null|             null|Oh, I see. Fancy ...|               0| 1192450646|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299ar|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299ar|t1_c0299ah|  1427426409|    3|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  3|
|    true|       Percept|                  null|             null|         testing ...|               0| 1192450656|         null|    0| false|     0|c0299as|t3_5yba3|t1_c0299as|  t3_5yba3|  1427426409|    1|       false|reddit.com|        t5_6|  1|
```

I parse data and I only show body column.I want to clean(filter) [deleted] comments and non latin alphabet comments in body column. How can I do that? (Note : Data Size=32 GB)

```
body:[Deleted]
body:How can I do that?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following code-snippet is meant for `Scala`, but you can try and adapt it for `Java`*

---

Use the [`Dataset.filter(..)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@filter(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) method as follows

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

val filteredData: DataFrame = dirtyData.
  filter(dirtyData("body") =!= "[Deleted]" && dirtyData("body").rlike("[\\x00-\\x7F]"))
```

---

Explanation

- `dirtyData("body") =!= "[Deleted]"` drops all rows where column `body` has value `[Deleted]` (you might want to handle *upper & lower case* too). See [`Column =!=`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@=!=(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
- `dirtyData("body").rlike("[\\x00-\\x7F]")` drops all rows where `body` does NOT contain an `ASCII` character (I haven't researched much on this part, but you can look for a better `regex`). See [`Column.rlike(..)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@rlike(literal:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

---

References

- [Filtering rows based on column values in spark dataframe scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374989/filtering-rows-based-on-column-values-in-spark-dataframe-scala)
- [How to filter out rows from spark dataframe containing unreadable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784456/how-to-filter-out-rows-from-spark-dataframe-containing-unreadable-characters)
- [Regular expression to match any ASCII character](https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/regular-expression-to-match-any-ascii-character)

Comment: thank you so much your comment .I  will trying all step. @y2k